# UPS > An unexpected error has occured > How to fix this issue?

Tags: user-profile-service

1. I recreated UPS about 6 times now and still getting the above error. I will include the ULS log at the end.
2. I followed all the rules
3. Services started in SP. forefront stated (2 FIMS R RUNing under farm act) in windows service
4. I followed this link www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx
5. yes, ran iisreset

===== Windows Log ======

```
.Net SqlClient Data Provider: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: HostId is not registered
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Data.Exception.DataAccessExceptionManager.ThrowException(SqlException innerException)
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Data.DataAccess.RetrieveWorkflowDataForHostActivator(Int16 hostId, Int16 pingIntervalSecs, Int32 activeHostedWorkflowDefinitionsSequenceNumber, Int16 workflowControlMessagesMaxPerMinute, Int16 requestRecoveryMaxPerMinute, Int16 requestCleanupMaxPerMinute, Boolean runRequestRecoveryScan, Boolean& doPolicyApplicationDispatch, ReadOnlyCollection`1& activeHostedWorkflowDefinitions, ReadOnlyCollection`1& workflowControlMessages, List`1& requestsToRedispatch)
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Workflow.Hosting.HostActivator.RetrieveWorkflowDataForHostActivator()
```

=========== here is the uls log ==============

```
02/09/2012 11:07:19.83  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (GET:http://ndcAppServer14:2010/_layouts/ManageUserProfileServiceApplication.aspx?ApplicationID=3fcd4fe8%2D8d2e%2D43f0%2D835b%2Dafcf536124d3)  e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
02/09/2012 11:07:19.83  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Site=/  e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
02/09/2012 11:07:19.85  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Foundation   General 8e1f    High    Failed to find the XML file at location '14\Template\Features\ReportServerCentralAdmin\feature.xml' e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
02/09/2012 11:07:19.85  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Foundation   Feature Infrastructure  fs74    Medium  Feature definition missing for Feature 'ReportServerCentralAdmin' (Id: '5f2e3537-91b5-4341-86ff-90c6a2f99aae')  e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
02/09/2012 11:07:19.85  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Foundation   General 8e1f    High    Failed to find the XML file at location '14\Template\Features\ReportServerStapling\feature.xml' e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
02/09/2012 11:07:19.85  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Foundation   Feature Infrastructure  fs74    Medium  Feature definition missing for Feature 'ReportServerStapling' (Id: '6bcbccc3-ff47-47d3-9468-572bf2ab9657')  e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
02/09/2012 11:07:19.85  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Foundation   General 8e1f    High    Failed to find the XML file at location '14\Template\Features\ReportServerCentralAdmin\feature.xml' e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
02/09/2012 11:07:19.85  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Foundation   Feature Infrastructure  fs74    Medium  Feature definition missing for Feature 'ReportServerCentralAdmin' (Id: '5f2e3537-91b5-4341-86ff-90c6a2f99aae')  e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
02/09/2012 11:07:19.85  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Foundation   General 8e1f    High    Failed to find the XML file at location '14\Template\Features\ReportServerStapling\feature.xml' e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
02/09/2012 11:07:19.85  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Foundation   Feature Infrastructure  fs74    Medium  Feature definition missing for Feature 'ReportServerStapling' (Id: '6bcbccc3-ff47-47d3-9468-572bf2ab9657')  e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
02/09/2012 11:07:19.85  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Foundation   General 8e1f    High    Failed to find the XML file at location '14\Template\Features\ReportServerCentralAdmin\feature.xml' e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
02/09/2012 11:07:19.85  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Foundation   Feature Infrastructure  fs74    Medium  Feature definition missing for Feature 'ReportServerCentralAdmin' (Id: '5f2e3537-91b5-4341-86ff-90c6a2f99aae')  e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
02/09/2012 11:07:19.86  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Foundation   General 8e1f    High    Failed to find the XML file at location '14\Template\Features\ReportServerStapling\feature.xml' e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
02/09/2012 11:07:19.86  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Foundation   Feature Infrastructure  fs74    Medium  Feature definition missing for Feature 'ReportServerStapling' (Id: '6bcbccc3-ff47-47d3-9468-572bf2ab9657')  e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
02/09/2012 11:07:19.86  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Portal Server    User Profiles   et8j    High    UserProfileServiceImportStatisticsWebPart:LoadControl failed, Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileImportJob.get_IsSynchronizationRunning()'.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.UserProfileServiceImportStatisticsWebPart._LoadStatusAndSettings()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.UserProfileServiceStatisticsWebPartBase.LoadControl(Object sender, EventArgs e)  e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
02/09/2012 11:07:19.86  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Foundation   General 8e1f    High    Failed to find the XML file at location '14\Template\Features\ReportServerCentralAdmin\feature.xml' e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
02/09/2012 11:07:19.86  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Foundation   Feature Infrastructure  fs74    Medium  Feature definition missing for Feature 'ReportServerCentralAdmin' (Id: '5f2e3537-91b5-4341-86ff-90c6a2f99aae')  e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
02/09/2012 11:07:19.86  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Foundation   General 8e1f    High    Failed to find the XML file at location '14\Template\Features\ReportServerStapling\feature.xml' e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
02/09/2012 11:07:19.86  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Foundation   Feature Infrastructure  fs74    Medium  Feature definition missing for Feature 'ReportServerStapling' (Id: '6bcbccc3-ff47-47d3-9468-572bf2ab9657')  e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
02/09/2012 11:07:19.88  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Foundation   General 8e1f    High    Failed to find the XML file at location '14\Template\Features\ReportServerCentralAdmin\feature.xml' e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
02/09/2012 11:07:19.88  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Foundation   Feature Infrastructure  fs74    Medium  Feature definition missing for Feature 'ReportServerCentralAdmin' (Id: '5f2e3537-91b5-4341-86ff-90c6a2f99aae')  e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
02/09/2012 11:07:19.88  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Foundation   General 8e1f    High    Failed to find the XML file at location '14\Template\Features\ReportServerStapling\feature.xml' e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
02/09/2012 11:07:19.88  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Foundation   Feature Infrastructure  fs74    Medium  Feature definition missing for Feature 'ReportServerStapling' (Id: '6bcbccc3-ff47-47d3-9468-572bf2ab9657')  e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
02/09/2012 11:07:19.88  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Foundation   Runtime tkau    Unexpected  System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.String Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.SynchronizationRunStatus.get_ConnectionName()'.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.UserProfileServiceImportStatisticsWebPart.RenderSectionContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.UserProfileServiceImportStatisticsWebPart.RenderWebPart(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
02/09/2012 11:07:19.88  w3wp.exe (0x01B8)   0x1024  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://ndcAppServer14:2010/_layouts/ManageUserProfileServiceApplication.aspx?ApplicationID=3fcd4fe8%2D8d2e%2D43f0%2D835b%2Dafcf536124d3)). Execution Time=48.1030410289576    e2037500-ef67-4363-a2d8-a4b343e2a050
```

Comment: What service packs, cumulative updates and hotfixes do you have installed?

Comment: Brand new install, no cu or sp? If you recommend then do I have to install cu or sp in certain order. The order they were released.

Comment: Install SP1 then just install the most recent CU. It will include all fixes since the Service Pack.

Comment: Always read the release notes (KB Article) for both the Service Pack and Cumulative updates. This isn't just a pharmaceutical 'always read the label' but absolutely mandatory that you do this before installing the cumulative update. It will tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: I followed this blog http://philwicklund.com/blog/Pages/Unexpected-error-when-browsing-to-User-Profile-Service-Application.aspx but it did not help.

Comment: I would hate to apply cu or sp as i m trying to mirror prod.

Comment: Ah ok, and I take it your prod isn't patched. Do you know if Windows Update has silently patched your install? (Check in Windows Update history in Control Panel).

Comment: If it's still the RTM version, then UPS was rather buggy and temperamental. Could you please check "Servers in Farm" from Central Admin and post your config DB version number?

Comment: - Windows updates are disabled till I am done with the Install.

Comment: - Config DB version #
Configuration database version: 14.0.6029.1000

Comment: @Matt Engel: Went to WFE (there is only one as it's a dev env) and both FIM are disabled.

Comment: @SPEveryone: Just added windows error logs produced by FIM to my original post.

Comment: I am fixing to download the sp and hotfix. It seems the hotfix4 site is down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. My RTM installation included SP1
2. So I did June CU in this order (http://sharepointsolutions.com/sharepoint-help/blog/2011/07/a-few-notes-on-sharepoint-2010-service-pack-1-and-the-june-cumulative-update/)
3. Prayed and deleted old UPS and restarted everything from scratch
4. for some reason "ups sync" locked up the spFarm account so I had Network Admin to unlock that account
5. Started ups sync and went fine
6. restarted Server (IISReset should be suff.)
7. boom. UPS stated working, able to add sync connection to ad, able to full sync
8. now runing people crawl.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's mentioned in the instructions on Harbar's site, but it is EXTREMELY important to hit every step perfectly.  Skipping one can cause the whole thing to blow up in your face.

Also, I had a similar issue and found that the UPS service was also trying to run on one of the other servers on the farm.  Check to make sure there's nothing lingering on one of the web front ends if you have them...

Good Luck!